# delegating subdomain traffic from godaddy to route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a domain in godaddy like testakc.com and trying to route traffic for my subdomain app.testakc.com to AWS Route53.

My app is hosted in AWS. So, I am trying to route my traffic from godaddy to Route53.

So, created a HostedZone for app.testakc.com in AWS and copied all the NS records and added the same in godaddy.

Still, ping app.testakc.com is not working and traffic is not going to AWS.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Unless the zone is large or requires separate management, it is not necessary to create another zone for `app.testakc.com`. Create one hosted zone for `testakc.com` and a resource record for `app.testakc.com`2) do not copy the name servers for a hosted zone for a subdomain to the registrar only the domain (`testakc.com`).

Comment: My static website testakc.com is outside AWS and being hosted by somebody else. I need only my subdomain in AWS.

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that you do not need to delegate a subdomain. Just add the correct resource record (A or CNAME) for `app` at `testakc.com`. Vastly simpler to manage.

Comment: Are you asking a question? Edit your question if you have left out important details.

Answer (score 0):

You want to delegate a zone to AWS route53 nameservers. Ok, good. Let's dig into the details.

First things first, the SLD.
At https://intodns.com/testakc.com we see that your
registrar setup is not doing a great job of delegating
from generic TLD servers to what I guess you intend is GoDaddy.
Note that `dig ns testakc.com @f1g1ns2.dnspod.net` (58.247.212.48) yields NXDOMAIN, no such domain, which is not good.

At this point I would usually move on to examine the `app` child zone,
but in this case you really need to tidy up the parent first.